# Validating the contents of a user entered string in Python?

Tags: python

As part of an assignment, I'm creating a program to ask a user to input a username and password.

I've completed the username part (easy), but in the assignment instructions, the password must:

- contain an uppercase character
- contain a lowercase character
- be longer than 6 characters
- contain a number
- have no white space

There are 5 specific error messages that need to display if any of these conditions are not true.

What I've got currently has some weird behavior, the errors only show up in a specific order (for example, password "f" will have the error "must have an uppercase character" instead of "must be longer than 6 characters"). I know this is because of the nesting order of the if statements, but if there's a better way... It also for some reason doesn't catch white space in the password. I know it probably isn't the most efficient way but here's what I've got so far:

```
def validatePassword():
    accept = "n"
    while accept == "n":
        password = input("Please enter a valid password: ")
        upper = "n"
        lower = "n"
        digit = "n"
        length = "n"
        white = "n"
        if len(password) >= 6:
            length = "y"
        for char in password:
            if char in string.ascii_uppercase:
                upper = "y"
            if char in string.ascii_lowercase:
                lower = "y"
            if char in string.digits:
                digit = "y"
            if char not in string.whitespace:
                white = "y"
        if upper == "y":
            if lower == "y":
                if digit == "y":
                    if length == "y":
                        if white == "y":
                            accept = "y"
                        else:
                            print("::: ERROR :::",password,"must not have any white space character.")
                    else:
                        print("::: ERROR :::",password,"must be longer than 6 characters.")
                else:
                    print("::: ERROR :::",password,"must contain a number.")
            else:
                print("::: ERROR :::",password,"must contain a lowercase character.")
        else:
            print("::: ERROR :::",password,"must contain an uppercase character.")

    return password
```

Comment: Try for a regex instead.

Comment: Not even sure what that is. I'm like 8 weeks into a 10 week introductory course.

Comment: Perhaps you should work with your [classmate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337727/python-password-verification-program).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def validatePassword(password):
    if not any(x.isupper() for x in password):
        return False, "No upper case character"

    if not any(x.islower() for x in password):
        return False, "No lower case character"

    if len(password) < 6:
        return False, "Not longer than 6 characters"

    if not any(x.isdigit() for x in password):
        return False, "No number"

    if any(x.isspace() for x in password):
        return False, "Contains hitespace"

    return True, ""


def test():
    # test some passwords
    test_passwords = ["lkjasdf", "KAJSDF", "lfSF", "asdfADSF", "asdf ADSF 123", "asdfADSF123"]
    for p in test_passwords:
        print validatePassword(p)

    # "real" usage
    while True:
        password = input("Please enter a valid password: ")
        result, message = validatePassword(password)
        if result is True:
            break
        else:
            print(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the correct way to do this is with `any()` and a generator expression, but seeing as how you said `I'm like 8 weeks into a 10 week introductory course` those probably don't help you.

Here's how you can do it without using any() by just looping through the characters checking for the presence of certain types of characters.

```
def validate_password(password):
    hasUpper = hasLower = hasNumber = hasWhiteSpace = False

    for char in passwordStr:
        if char.isupper():
            hasUpper = True
        if char.islower():
            hasLower = True
        if char.isdigit():
            hasNumber = True
        if char.isspace():
            hasWhiteSpace = True

    if len(password) <= 6:
        return False, "Password must be longer than 6 characters"
    if not hasUpper:
        return False, "Password must contain atleast one uppercase character"
    if not hasLower:
        return False, "Password must contain atleast one lowercase letter"
    if not hasNumber:
        return False, "Password must contain alteast one number"
    if hasWhiteSpace:
        return False, "Password cannot contain any white space"

    return True
```

Comment: I like the way this is structured, but what happens is it always returns the value True, and accepts the password.

Comment: I used a while loop in the main program:
    
    accept = False
    while accept = False
        password = getpass()
        accept = validatePassword(password)


The validate program should return either a true or false Boolean value to accept, and it should either continue or end the while loop. It just keeps ending immediately.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's the data type `bool` which can represent the values `True` and `False`. You should use them to represent simple true/false states instead of assigning the strings `"y"` and `"n"`.

Second, checking every character separately and storing whether the different conditions are met at least once is a possible way. However, Python has powerful string examination methods that can make your life much easier. Let me demonstrate them by writing a short function which takes aa password as argument and simply returns `True` or `False` depending on whether the passwords meets your restrictions:

```
def is_password_valid(password):

    # check password length:
    if len(password) < 6:
        print("Your password is too short, at least 6 characters are required!")
        return False

    # check if password contains any non-alphanumeric letters (including whitespace):
    # (isalnum() only returns true if the string only contains letters and digits, nothing else)
    if not password.isalnum():
        print("Your password may only contain letters and digits!")
        return False

    # check if password contains letters:
    # (isdigit() only returns true if all of the characters are numbers)
    if password.isdigit():
        print("Your password does not contain any letters!")
        return False

    # check if password contains uppercase letters:
    # (islower() only returns true if all of the letters are lowercase, non-letters are ignored)
    if password.islower():
        print("Your password does not contain any uppercase letters!")
        return False

    # check if password contains lowercase letters:
    # (isupper() only returns true if all of the letters are uppercase, non-letters are ignored)
    if password.isupper():
        print("Your password does not contain any lowercase letters!")
        return False

    # check if password contains lowercase numbers:
    # (isalpha() only returns true if all of the characters are letters)
    if password.isalpha():
        print("Your password does not contain any numbers!")

    # if all conditions above are okay, the password is valid:
    print("The password is okay.")
    return True
```

You may of course reorder the blocks in my code above as you wish.

You can then simply use this helper function inside your loop which looks a lot simpler and cleaner now:

```
def validate_password():
    accept = False
    while not accept:
        password = input("Please enter a valid password: ")
        accept = is_password_valid(password)
```

Comment: `if len(password) < 6:` should be `if len(password) <= 6:`

Comment: @Racialz That depends on whether we look at the OP's textual description or their code. While the text says "be longer than 6 characters", the code says "`if len(password) >= 6: length = "y"`". They should be able to adapt that if my interpretation is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Regular Expressions. If you don't know about regex, as you've mentioned in your comment, [this](http://regexr.com/) is a great website.

For validation, check if the password matches with any of the rules which will render it invalid and if not, it is a valid password.

```
import re
def validate(passwd):
  pattern = r'^(.{0,5}|[^0-9]*|[^A-Z]*|[^a-z]*|.*\s+.*)$'
  result = re.search(pattern, passwd)
  if result:
    print 'Invalid Password'
  else:
    print 'Valid Password'
```

What this does is check if, `passwd` is less than 6 chars OR contains no numbers OR contains no uppercase chars OR contains no lowercase chars OR contains spaces. If none of the criteria matches, the password is valid.